# Understanding the TKey and TValue parameters in the Dictionary class

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I've searched a bit, but I can't seem to find any information on the TKey and TValue parameters of the Dictionary class..

1. Is TKey just a value you specify to make a TValue unique?
2. Is TValue just a value of your own decision that doesn't have any impact on the search of the Dictionary class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dictionary is a mapping of keys to values.

`TKey` is the *type* of the key. `TValue` is the *type* of the value.

So for example, if I were mapping `string` to `Person` (because I had a collection of people and I wished to be able to find one by name quickly) I'd use a

```
Dictionary<string, Person>
```

Note that the key doesn't make the *value* unique. There can be two keys which use the same value. However, each key is only associated with one value.

Comment: Somebody stop this man! His quicker, more accurate, more comprehensive and more knowledgeable answers will be the death of us mortals! ;)

Comment: @BernhardHofmann i am sure 1 day that points he has earned will overflow :)

Answer (score 1):

You're correct on both counts. The key is a unique value of the type you specify when you create a dictionary, and the value is any valid value for the value type you define when you create the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Scroll down to remarks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. Yes.

---

Parameters prefixed with 'T' are just placeholders for a Type.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary stores a Key-Value-Pair. You can take anything for to be the value and the key. You decide it, when you create such a dictionary. E.g.:

```
Dictionary<int, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

With that you get a dictionary taking a string for to be a value and an integer for its key. It depends on what you need!

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is also known as an [associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), or a map.

It is a generic container just like `List(T)` and it contains items of type `TValue`. You can thus use the generic type `TValue` to determine the type of each element.

The key is what you use to index each item. The difference between a dictionary and a list or array is that the index for a dictionary is not restricted to being an integer. It also does not need to be contiguous. Thus the type you specify for `TKey` does not need to be an integer. Very often `string` is used.

This allows you to write something like:

```
Dictionary<string, int> Reputation = new Dictionary<string, int>();
Reputation["Jon Skeet"] = 360737;//and counting
```

If you then need to retrieve this value you can write:

```
int rep = Reputation["Jon Skeet"];//rep now contains the value 360737
```

If someone upvotes then you can write:

```
Reputation["Jon Skeet"] += 10;
```

and so on.

Comment: I think you're coming to this from a delphi perspective - the tag is C#. We don't have TDictionary etc, just Dictionary and IDictionary :)